# I have removed a user from the sudoers file but he still have root acces

Tags: sudo

i want to prevent all the users from becoming a root user

i have a user called sohaib i removed him from the sudo group using

```
gpasswd -d sohaib sudo
```

and also i've edited the **/etc/sudoers** file , i have commented the

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

but the user still can use the

```
sudo -i
```

and become a root , i don't wanna any user to become a root including the first created user too (sohab)

Comment: perhaps there's a file in the `/etc/sudoers.d` folder granting the user sudo access

Comment: you are right , I've find a 90-cloud-init-users file that has some rules ,  it grants that user access without a password

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to *also* change all the relevant files in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory, specifically a file called `90-cloud-init-users`.